# Spring Cloud: Confused Deputy

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I have a question about secure downstream calls between microservices for ecosystem based on Spring Cloud Netflix (Zuul, Eureka), Spring Security OAuth and Spring Cloud Security.

For example I have the WEB Application (WEB) and the following microservices: A, B, X, Y, Z.

Where:

- All services (A, B, X, Y, Z) deployed in the perimeter and have direct physical access to each other.
- API Gateway based on Netflix Zuul performs authentication function for all services deployed to the perimeter.
- All Services accepts OAuth token for authorization.

And:

1. A should have access to services X and Y (some actions)
2. B should have access to services Y and Z (some actions)
3. Calling all services must be made in the context of authenticated user (for authorization).

And I want to solve the following problems (the confused deputy problem):

1. The service A should not be able to perform any actions for service Z (even if authenticated user has necessary permissions for Z).

For example:
User has the permissions to perform actions READ, WRITE, DELETE for service Z.

But service A shouldn't be able to perform any action for service Z behalf on authenticated user.

2. The service A should be able to perform only granted actions for service X.

For example:

User has the permissions to perform actions READ, WRITE, DELETE for service X.

But service A should be able to perform only READ action for service X behalf on authenticated user.

Is there a any solution (with current technologies) to these problems out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that it is logically the user who is performing these actions, and he has to have authorized them, implicitly or explicitly. With that in mind, I know of one approach, at least, that would work (the UAA in cloudfoundry does this). You can extend the namespace of your scopes to include the service id, eg "X.READ", "Z.WRITE".